# Summing a fortran array with mask

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I have a fortran array a(i,j). I wish to sum it on dimension 2(j) with a mask that j is not equal to i.

i.e,

```
a1=0
do j=1,n
if(j.ne.i) then
a1=a1+a(i,j)
endif
enddo
```

What is the way of doing this using the intrinsic sum function in fortran as I found the intrinsic to be much faster than the explicit loop.
I thought of trying sum(a(i,:),j.ne.i), but this is naturally giving error. Also if one can suggest how to only some the values of a(i,:) where abs(a(i,j)) is greater than, say 0.01, it would be helpful.

Comment: I do not think the intrinsic can be faster than a well written loop. It does the same thing. And you have to construct the mask array for the intrinsic. Rather than that you should think how to avoid the branching.

Comment: Another point is as well think about the order of the loops (Fortran is column major, whilst e.g. C is row major).

Comment: To answer your first, question `sum(a) - sum([(a(i:i), i = 1, n)])`.

Comment: @evets For some reason I am getting the exact same run time for this one liner and for the nested do loop with the if condition. Perhaps gfortran is making some transformations here.

Comment: @VladimirF, I suspect that for large `n`, the one liner may be problematic for two reason. First, the array constructor may flush/reload  the memory cache for each value in the implied-do.  Second, I would be cautious with the one liner from a numerical rounding/cancellation viewpoint.  As to the speed issue, if the test is too simple, gfortran may optimize away the summation (ie., the compiler computes it at runtime).

Comment: @evets The test involved random arrays and did differ for the split-loop in my answer.

Comment: @user157588 use `/=` instead of `.ne.`. it improves readability.

Comment: For large size, the intrinsic is almost 2 to 3 times faster in my machine, even by alterning the nested do loop from do i=1,n,j=n a(i,j) to do j=1,n,i=1,n a(i,j). I am using gfortran, processor is intel i5-7200U. Also, summing an array by sum is much faster than explicitly constructing a do loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last question, you can use the `WHERE` construct to build a mask.  For example,

```
 logical :: y(3,3) = .false.
 real x(3,3)
 x = 1
 x(1,1) = 0.1
 x(2,2) = 0.1
 x(3,3) = 0.1
 print * , sum(x)
 where(abs(x) > 0.25) y = .true.
 print *, sum(x,y)
 end
```

Whether this is better than nested do-loops is questionable.

Comment: Or even `y = abs(x) > 0.25` or dispense with intermediates altogether and write `sum(x,abs(x) > 0.25`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I like your reply better than mine!  Of course, I've now introduced OP with a new Fortran construct, namely, `WHERE`.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily avoid any branching for the off-diagonal case. It should be much faster than creating any mask array and checking the mask. Branching (conditional jumps) is costly even when branch prediction can be very efficient.

```
do j=1,n
  do i = 1,j-1
    a1=a1+a(i,j)
  end do

  do i = j+1,n
    a1=a1+a(i,j)
  end do
end do
```

If you need your code to be fast and not short, you should test this kind of approach. In my tests it is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

I find that summing the whole array then subtracting sum of diagonal elements can be 2x faster.

```
  a1 = 0
  do i = 1, n 
    a1 = a1 + a(i,i)
  end do 
  a1 = sum(a) - a1
  end do
```

Comment: In my tests it is quite slow, the slowest of the approaches shown here.

Comment: I tested with `ifort` using `/O3` flag. With GNU Fortran, I see no difference though. Also, the array size can affect the results, I used a large `10k x 10k` array.

Comment: Depending on the summands and the order of summation, you may have numerical issues.  For example, subtraction of large nearly identical factors can lead to catastrophic cancellation, which may occur with a large diagonally dominate matrix.